# Including org src blocks literally

Tags: org-mode

I'm editing an HTML file that also contains CSS and Javascript. I would like to keep this in an Org file with each in separate blocks like

```
#+BEGIN_SRC css
CSS code ...
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC js
Javascript code ...
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC html
html ...
#+END_SRC
```

so that when I edit the blocks with "C-c '" I can be in the proper mode. However the HTML block needs to include (substitute) the other 2 blocks verbatim, but Org wants to "evaluate" them, which doesn't make sense in this case. I haven't found a way to make a variable contain a whole named block literally and then be substituted. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to use the literate capabilities of org mode, with noweb reference:

```
#+name: mycss
#+begin_src css
  This is css
#+end_src

#+name: myjs
#+begin_src js
  this is js
#+end_src

#+name: myhtlm
#+begin_src html :noweb yes
  <html>
    <head>
      <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        <<mycss>>
      </style>
      <code>
        <<myjs>>
      </code>
    </head>
  </html>
#+end_src
```

`<<mycss>>` and `<<myjs>>` are noweb reference, that will be replaced by the content of the mycss and myjs source block

Comment: Thank you very much! I never quite understood how the noweb thing worked but this is probably what I want. But when I hit "C-c C-c" on the "#+begin_src html" line it says "org-babel-execute-src-block: No org-babel-execute function for html!". How do I make it create the output?

Comment: OK, poking around I discovered org-babel-expand-src-block which seems to expand correctly. I puts it in a temp buffer it creates, but I'm wondering if there are other ways to do this. Ultimately I will want this in a file which I upload to S3. Is there a way I can script this with elisp or possibly in some Org-style?

Comment: (org-babel-expand-noweb-references) seems to be what I was looking for. Once I get the point inside the block and call that it returns it as a string. Thanks again.